# How to shift (or transform) a TikZ path defined by named coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, transformation

I wonder if it is possible to shift (or apply any another transformation) a path that is defined by named coordinates.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  
  \draw[blue,thick] (A) -- (B);
  
  \draw[red, dashed, yshift=1cm] (A) -- (B); % shift not working
  
  \draw[green!50!black, dashed, yshift=1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0); % shift working
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT : Here is another example including a scaling :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  
  \draw[blue,thick] (A) -- (B);
  
  \draw[red, dashed, yshift=1cm, scale=2] (A) -- (B); % transformations not working
  
  \draw[green!50!black, dashed, yshift=1cm, scale=2] (0,0) -- (2,0); % transformation working
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the behavior is different with explicit rather than with named coordinates? Isn't the name just an alias?

Comment: `\draw[red, dashed] ([shift={(0cm,1cm)}]A) -- ([shift={(0cm,1cm)}]B);` is one way

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with a more generic use case. I don't understand why named coordinates are not processed the same way as explicit ones...

Comment: There's no good hook for this. In the past, I just defined a short style, say `*/.style={<transformations>}` and applied them to each coordinate (and the path itself if necessary). That way you don't have to repeat the transformation at each coordinate.

Comment: Because coordinates (like nodes) are fixed points on the paper. They're supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Would you be happy with an answer that transforms the path after it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TikZ already supports coordinate transformations. See the manual [Section 25.3](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.3). There's a tricky scoping issue though, that I'll walk you through.

When you use `\coordinate (A) at (0,0);` you're associating the coordinate `(0,0)` *in the current coordinate system* to the name `(A)`. If you try to apply a transformation local to the path using a named coordinate, TikZ purposefully looks up the coordinate in the coordinate system it was bound in. In fact, this exact issue was marked as an [intentional "won't fix"](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/456) on the bug tracker because it's the intended behavior.

You can, however, wrap the coordinate assignment into a scope that is transformed, and your named coordinates will be adjusted as you expect.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1cm, scale=2]
      \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  
      \draw[blue,thick] (A) -- (B);
  
      \draw[red, dashed] (A) -- (B); % transformations NOW working
  
      \draw[green!50!black, dashed] (0,0) -- (2,0); % transformation working
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want this to apply to the entire picture, you can move it up into the options of the `tikzpicture` itself, i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` (`yshift`-ing the entire picture won't have a visible effect.)

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the canvas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  
  \draw[blue] (A) -- (B);
  
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=1cm,scale=4}]
    \draw[red, dashed,line width=\pgflinewidth/4] (A) -- (B);
  \end{scope}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `transform canvas` do the job for a shift, but it doesn't for others such as scaling, since it modifies the lines width...

Comment: @Tobard You can scale down the lines accordingly, say you have a scaling factor of 4, then you could do `\begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=4}]
    \draw[red, dashed,line width=\pgflinewidth/4] (A) -- (B);
  \end{scope}`

Comment: Unfortunately this patch does not conserve the dashed settings.

Comment: @Tobard You can do the very same for the dashes. Have a look at the tikz user guide to see how their lengths and gaps can be adjusted.

Comment: Yes, of course... But that's not sounds like an 'elegant' solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can shift the individual coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  
  \draw[blue,thick] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[red, dashed] ([yshift=.5cm]A) -- ([yshift=.5cm]B);
  \draw[green!50!black, dashed, yshift=1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0); % shift working
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick, it does the job for a shift, but I would like a solution that works with other transformations as well. I've just added a use case with a scaling.